# Return unrated rows from a MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I have a system where people rate items, and I have two tables, I want to only show the user items they have not rated.

```
item (i and simplified for this example)
----
item_id, name
1, widget1
2, widget2
```

I have a rating table, which stores three columns

```
rating
------
item_id
user_id
rating
```

So I want to only return results that that user has not yet rated, now I did try this;

### psuedo-query

```
SELECT * FROM item LEFT JOIN rating r ON r.item_id = i.item_id WHERE r.user_id != USER_ID_OF_THE_USER;
```

However that still returned items that they had rated, as other people had rated the item...

So if I have 100 items in the database, user a has rated 30 and user b has rated 70... then user a should get the 70 items they have to rate, and user b should get the 30 items they havent rated.

My rating table has a compound unique key, so if they rate item_id = 1 once, and rate it again, it just updates the rating value, it doesnt make a new row. One row is inserted for every item that is rated by a user.

This feels like it should be easy and it probably is, but I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming every user has to rate every item.  If so, then you can do this with `not exists`:

```
select *
from item i
where not exists (
    select 1
    from rating r
    where i.item_id = r.item_id and r.user_id = ?)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e822c/1)

---

Give the fact you're using `mysql`, a `left join / null` check would probably be faster:

```
select i.*
from item i
    left join rating r on i.item_id = r.item_id and r.user_id = ?
where r.user_id is null
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e822c/3)
- http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Comment: This worked. 

Do you feel this is a suitably elegant approach, the schema I have designed is going to have many rows, but the column count is low.

Is there anything I can to to ensure optimisation, beyond indexes on user_id/item_id.

Comment: @djldn -- actually with `mysql`, `outer join / null` checks generally perform better.  Here's a good article on the subject: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Comment: Yes, the anti-join pattern is the way to go.  (The edit to this answer beat my answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Just use an anti-join pattern, like this:

```
 SELECT i.*
   FROM item i 
   LEFT
   JOIN rating r
     ON r.item_id = i.item_id
    AND r.user_id =   USER_ID_OF_THE_USER
  WHERE r.user_id IS NULL
```

The outer join returns all rows from item, along with rating by the user. If there is no related row from the `rating` table, then the values of the columns from `rating` will be NULL. So all we need is to add a `WHERE` clause to filter out the rows that had a match.

Comment: Even though slightly slower than my edits, still +1 imo -- explanation alone is helpful.  I generally use `not exists`, however with `mysql` it just doesn't perform as well.

Comment: @sgeddes: I thought the MySQL optimizer was getting better about recognizing the `NOT EXISTS subquery` equivalence to anti-join. In 5.6? Or 5.7? Or maybe I'm thinking mariadb? I still remember back in the day (MySQL 3.x) when the optimizer didn't support subqueries. The anti-join is the pattern I prefer. +1 on your answer, for including the anti-join pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM item i
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT * FROM rating r 
    WHERE r.item_id = i.item_id 
    AND r.user_id = USER_ID_OF_THE_USER);
```

This will return you those items for which there is no rating of user USER_ID_OF_THE_USER.

Comment: Almost - it needs to be = not != but I think this works.

Comment: It needs to be `=` since it uses `NOT EXISTS`. The way it is written should work. Let me know if it doesn't.